# How to unlock a locked user in openldap

Tags: openldap

We have a user who locked itself by using a faulty password.

We have a standard openldap install following [the LTS server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.htm).

The locked user has an extra attribute now that it got locked:

```
pwdAccountLockedTime: 201702161256Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find [how to unlock openldap password](https://serverfault.com/a/336086/355817)

> - Set `pwdLockoutDuration` attribute to some amount; the value is in seconds. I think that by default it is 0 (infinite).
> - Unlock the account manually without need for resetting the password by removing the operational attribute `pwdAccountLockedTime`.

Comment: I used your second method , I deleted the pwdAccountLockedTime attribute from the user. Thanks !